# Firebase Sign in with phone number suddenly stopped working

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

We are using firebase ui to sign in with phone number
Everything was working fine but suddenly it started giving us an error on recaptcha, so we implemented google play integrity.

The error disappeared and we have a new error now:

> keyset not found, will generate a new one
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: can't read keyset; the pref value
> GenericIdpKeyset does not exist
> at
> com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzdy.zzc(SourceFile:13)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzdy.zza(Unknown
> Source:0)

We checked the sha1 and sha256 on Firebase and made sure they are correct.

The firebase UI is at 8.0.2

We are still not able to receive the SMS

When clicking verify, the browser is opening, showing an empty page, then going back to the application. Test numbers are working fine.